# options required for finding/checking data from a list in multiple workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of data in one workbook that needs to be crosschecked in multiple workbooks to see if the same data appears eg a company name appears in workbook. how can i do this? excel 2003
I usually visually check each workbook page by page for over twenty different companies. I know I can use find but i have multiple values to look up/find in multiple sheets and in multiple workbooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not 100% but i dont think excel can (without code) cross examine 2 workbooks. if it does i would say the data validation tool would do it.

failing that you would need some code (VBA Code) which is manually written macros that can handle multiple workbooks.

Hope That Helps!